# Definition of a compact topos

Tags: category-theory, definition, compactness, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

This is in continuation of the previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563786/two-equivalent-notions-of-compactness/3563808#3563808). I know what a compact topos: $F$ *in $Set$* is:

> $F$ is compact if the geometric morphism $\gamma: F \rightarrow Set$ preserves directed suprema of subojects of $1$.

I am looking at the paper [Moerdijk, Vermeulen](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39699346.pdf) pg 6

> **Def 1.3.** A map $f: F \rightarrow E$ of topos is *proper* if it renders $F$ compact as an $E$ topos.

What does this mean *precisely?*

Comment: IIRC, a map of topological spaces $f : X \to Y$ is said to be proper if whenever $K \subseteq Y$ is compact, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.  I wonder if this definition reduces to that condition in that special case.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it means that $f$ preserves directed suprema subobjects of $1$. However at least for my topos-theoretic level the definition seems a bit ambiguous-I’m not sure whether some aspect of this should be interpreted internally to $E$. An $E$-topos is just a topos with a map to $E$, a generalization of the way in which every cocomplete topos has a canonical map to Set.

Comment: Yea, that's what I guessed too, but I don't know how to justify this as the  "correct" generalization.

Comment: I think my main concern here is that you can have another definition: that $f$ prserves direced suprema of subobjects that equals $1$. In the case of set these coincide.